# has_many to has_many ...do I have to add_index both ways?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am pretty new to Rails. I am wondering if I need to add_index to both migrations?

I am trying to define users and events. Each user can have many events and each event can have many users. so i would do something like this right:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :events
.
.
.
```

and then this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :users
.
.
.
```

Do I need to add_index for both like this:

```
add_index :events, :user_id
```

and then

```
add_index :users, :event_id
```

Are these assumptions correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even without 'indexes' your code will work, But as a best practice its good to use 'indexes' which will make your queries faster

check here

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/21-always-add-db-index

HTH

sameera

Answer (score 1):

Pretty cool [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) about many-to-many relationships.